# How to pass JSON object throught the REST URL

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-apicontroller

I Have a method GetCustomerDetails in WEBUI controller(below)

```
public bool GetCustomerDetails(string customer)
        {
            Uri CustUri = null;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://online/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/customers/", customer).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                CustUri = response.Headers.Location;
            }
            return false;
}

the above method has to hit the below method(API controller). 


 public string PostCustomer(string customerJsonString)
        {
            CustomerDetailDto customer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerDetailDto>(customerJsonString);
            bool res = _customerService.SaveOrUpdateCustomer(customer);
        if (res)
                  {
            ....
          }
   return something;
            }
```

but in response(WEBUI above) i am getting error msg as

> {StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed', Version: 1.1,
>   Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: {   Pragma: no-cache 
>   Connection: Close   Cache-Control: no-cache   Date: Wed, 17 Jul 2013
>   12:17:49 GMT   Server: ASP.NET   Server: Development   Server:
>   Server/11.0.0.0   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319   Content-Length: 73
>   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8   Expires: -1 }}

so can any body help me in fixing the issue.

Comment: could you share your request headers and request

Answer (score 1):

I am so sorry to be too late in answering to your question and hope your solution is already implemented. I am posting this solution so as to help others who come across the same situation.

The API Controller method PostCustomer **MUST** include an Allow header containing a list of valid methods. So we have the below implementation.

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public string PostCustomer(string customerJsonString)
    {
        CustomerDetailDto customer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerDetailDto>(customerJsonString);
        bool res = _customerService.SaveOrUpdateCustomer(customer);
    if (res)
              {
        ....
      }
return something;
        }
```

Adding the HttpPost header would thus help your WebUI Controller to talk to the above method.

Thanks,
Neeraj